# What's the proper mathematical form for the sum of forces equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

I handed in a paper on the Second Law of Physics with a form I found in a textbook.  It described the Second Law as a "Sum of Forces":

$$\sum_i F_i=ma$$
My teacher says this is incorrect because the force law is a 'vector' law.  I'm confused about this because I thought the result of a sum was a scalar. What is the right way to think about the "sum of forces" equation?  Why does my textbook give this form if it's not correct?

Comment: You can sum vectors and the sum of a set of vectors is a vector; if you take a basis, you end up with three scalar equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mathematical vector obeys two laws of algebra.

- **Scalar law** - The multiplication of a scalar value $\lambda$ with a vector $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector where each element is multiplied (individually).

$$ \lambda \mathbf{a} =\lambda \pmatrix{a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n} = \pmatrix{\lambda a_1 \\ \lambda a_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda a_n} $$

- **Adition law** - The addition of two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector where each element is added (individually).
  $$ \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} = \pmatrix{a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n} +\pmatrix{b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n} = \pmatrix{a_1+b_1 \\ a_2+b_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n+b_n} $$

A force vector, or a velocity vector, or an acceleration vector still obey the same laws of a mathematical vector.

So the sum of forces is a vector where each component ($x$, $y$ and $z$) are added separately.

$$ \mathbf{F}_1 + \mathbf{F}_2 = \pmatrix{F_{1x} + F_{2x} \\ F_{1y} + F_{2y} \\ F_{1z} + F_{2z} } $$

So the proper form of Newton's second law is

$$ \sum_i \mathbf{F}_i = m\, \mathbf{a}_{\rm C} $$ where point *C* is the center of mass. This is direct result of the *definition* of linear momentum as $$\mathbf{p} = m\, \mathbf{v}_{\rm C} $$ and the second law $$\sum_i \mathbf{F}_i = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \mathbf{p}$$

Comment: Are you saying that if I had made the F and the a bold (to indicate a vector), then my formula would be correct?  Is that what OX90 is doing with the arrow over the letters?

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury Yes.  Vectors are usually denoted in one of two ways.  The first is with bold face, as ja72 is doing here.  The second is with an arrow over the top.  They're equivalent — at least for your purposes.

Comment: It does not matter if you bold, or do an overarrow or a bar or ... As long as you denote a vector (collection of $n$ elements all measured from the same coordinate fame). @Mike there are numerous ways to denote vectors, not just 2.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury My point is that vectors follow some mathematical rules and to have physical vectors (following the same rule) you have to denote _what_ you are measuring, from _where_ and along what _direction_. Often most of the above are implied, and only the _what_ needs to be specified. Like: $\mathbf{v}_A$ the velocity of point A.

Comment: @ja72 **u·su·al·ly** *adverb* indicating something that is to be expected by reason of previous experience, which shows it to occur more often than not.  Do you really think a person asking a question at this level is likely to see another form more often than not?  Did I imply that those are the only two that will be found in any context?

Answer (score 1):

You are both right, when you work in an [inertial frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference) and the system of interest has a constant mass:

$$\sum_i \vec{F}_i=m\vec{a}$$

If $A=B$ then $B=A$ or "A is B", thus it has also the same dimensions.

In particular, if the forces satisfy: $\vec{F}_i \in \mathbb{R}^N$ then for any finite sum of forces $S = \sum_i \vec{F}_i $ this holds: $S \in \mathbb{R}^N$ (vector spaces are closed under addition). Therefore, we can conclude that $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

In classical systems $N=3$.

Note: $S$ is also a vector, though I was sloppy to omit the $\vec{}$ sign intentionally.

---

In general, the second law takes the form $\vec{F} = \frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}$ where $\vec{P}= m \vec{V}$ is the momentum and $\vec{V}$ is the velocity.

Comment: You _have_ to specify the location where the acceleration vector is measured. The law doesn't apply to any point on a body, but only on the center of mass.

Answer (score 0):

Force is a vector. So you need to do vector addition i.e. you need to take into account the direction of each force. You may have to break down each force in to its horizontal and vertical components and then add them respectively(not forgetting the directions)
For example if there is an upward force of 10N and downward force of 6N then resultant is 4N
Similarly if one force is horizontal and the other vertical then you need to use the vector addition formula